# Adverb & verb- correct placement?

Tags: word-order, adverb-position

Should it be 'Globally recognised' or 'Recognised globally'?
I think it should be globally recognised following the rule of- Adverb before verb- but am not sure.
Also, should it be 'beautifully drawn' or 'drawn beautiflly'?

Comment: You mention 'the rule of _adverb before verb_. Where did you find this? Does _She beautifully sings_ sound acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're using the phrase. If "recognized" or "drawn" are functioning as adjectives instead of verbs (e.g., a "globally recognized" movie star, or a "beautifully drawn" picture), then the adverbs would come first.

It likewise would be in this order if you are writing the sentence in passive voice (e.g., she is "globally recognized," or the picture is "beautifully drawn").

However, if you are writing the sentence in active voice, the adverbs may come either before the verbs or after the verbs and at the end of the sentences depending on the way the adverbs function. Adverbs of manner (most adverbs ending in -ly) either fall before the verb (e.g., We globally recognize the United Nations) or at the end of the sentence (e.g., We recognize the United Nations globally). Adverbs of evaluation, however, always fall after the adverb and usually at the end of the sentence (e.g., The artist drew the picture beautifully).